# onPostExecute() invoked before doInBackground() method in the case of AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Consider the code below:

```
package com.reallybelievebig.asynctaskextracredit;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AsyncTaskTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = AsyncTaskTestActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_async_task_test);

        new TestTask().execute("Execute");

        Log.d(TAG, "In UI Thread!");
    }

    private class TestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i+=20) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception Caught: ", e);
                }

                publishProgress(i);
            }

            return "Background Task Complete";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            Toast.makeText(AsyncTaskTestActivity.this, "Progress: " + values[0], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            Log.d(TAG, "In onPostExecute: " + s);
            Toast.makeText(AsyncTaskTestActivity.this, s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

1. I am starting an asynchronous task from the main UI thread using `TestTask.execute()` method.
2. The `doInBackground()` method is working fine. It sleeps for some time, invokes the `publishProgress()` method and displays the Toast in `onProgressUpdate()` method.
3. I was expecting that the `onPostExecute()` method to be called only after the `doInBackground()` is completed. However as soon as I start the Application, I get the Log message in `onPostExecute()` method.

There is something wrong which I am not able to figure out. What is the issue in this code?

Comment: The `doInBackground()` method is only going to take about a quarter-second. Your Toasts show asynchronously at 3.5 seconds each, so `onPostExecute()` will run well before the Toasts are done.

Comment: use logs instead of toasts.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes that was the problem. Now I understood!. Thanks

Comment: @RahulTiwari: Yes logs will show the real working. Thanks